# How to check RAM channel?

Tags: 20.04, ram

How to check if my ram is dual channel or not? Is there a piece of software similar to CPU Z to check this?

Comment: Are you chasing an error or problem?

Comment: Not really, I just bought RAM and I want to see if dual channel works with my RAM

Comment: So nothing to do with Ubuntu it is a hardware question. Toms Hardware is a good place for questions like that.

Comment: But this is in Ubuntu, I want to know how .. In windows I can easily check it using CPU Z .. How about in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

`sudo dmidecode --type memory` should show you if your hardware supports dual channel (look at `Locator` / `Bank Locator` for dual channel motherboards it will say something like `ChannelA-DIMM0` `ChannelB-DIMM1` etc.

But that does not show if the ram is working at a particular bandwidth. From what I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1092324/cant-get-dual-channel-memory-status-from-linux-why/1621323#1621323) the only way I know is to run memtest86 and look at the `Mode` 64, 128, 196, 256bit for single, dual, triple and quad channel

Comment: Thanks mate, this information is very useful for me .. And finally I know that my RAM is working on dual channel

Comment: `dmidecode -t memory` gives me empty output: `# dmidecode 3.3 Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs. SMBIOS 2.5 present`

Answer (score 2):

`dmidecode` is the tool for anything memory related

Long version:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17
```

Look for "size" for the amount and "channel" or "locator" for the banknumber.

Filtered on size or channel and printing it with RAM ...

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="\t" } /Size|Channel/ { line = (line ? line OFS : "") $2 } /^$/ { print line; line="RAM" }' | grep -iv 'no'
```

Comment: I get notifications like this:
4096 MB RAM ChannelA-DIMM0
4096 MB ChannelB-DIMM0 RAM

How do I confirm whether it is single channel or dual channel?

Comment: Channel A and Channel B Looks Dual to me...Is it that simple?

Comment: yes it is that simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Translate from Indonesian :

For Linux distributions (x86 and x86_64), to check information about RAM channels, you can use the following command:

sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep Channel
The output that appears should be like this:

```
Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
```

You can see ChannelA and ChannelB, meaning RAM is running in dual channel mode. If nothing appears, it means a single channel.

Source : https://id.quora.com/Bagaimana-cara-cek-RAM-apakah-single-channel-atau-dual-channel-di-Ubuntu